# Add a Click Event to elements added to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 var myOP = '<div>';
 for (var i = 0; i < op.length; i++) {
     myOP += '<div>';
     myOP += '<div id="myBTN-' + [i] + '">' + op[i]['Field1'] + '</div>';
     myOP += '<div id="blah-' + [i] + '">' + op[i]['Field2'] + '</div>';
     myOP += '</div>';
 }
 myOP += '</div>';
 $("#myBTN-" + i).click(function () {
     $('#blah-' + i).toggle("slow");
 });
 $('#container').html(myOP);
```

I'm trying to get the click function to fire on the elements i'm created w/ the above for loop. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
var myOP = '<div>';
for (var i = 0; i < op.length; i++) {
    myOP += '<div>';
    myOP += '<div id="myBTN-' + [i] + '">' + op[i]['Field1'] + '</div>';
    myOP += '<div id="blah-' + [i] + '">' + op[i]['Field2'] + '</div>';
    myOP += '</div>';
}
myOP += '</div>';
$(myOP).appendTo('#container').find('div[id^="myBTN"]').click(function () {$(this).next().toggle("slow")});
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as the element is just a `String`, you won't be able to add a handler. You have to add the handler *after*  `$('#container').html(myOP)`;

You could try exploring the idea of [event delegation](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/30/event-delegation-in-javascript/). Using that, your could do something like:

```
$('#container').on('click', function(e){
  e = e || event;
  var from = e.target || e.srcElement, i;
  if (from.id && /^mybttn/i.test(from.id)){
   i = +((from.id.match(/\d{0,}$/)||[-1])[0]);
   if (i>=0){
    $('#blah'+i).toggle('slow');
   }
  } 
});​
```

[​Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/H7kGZ/)

Alternatively you could

```
 $('#container').html(myOP);
 $('div[id^="myBTN-"]').on('click',function(){
     $('#blah-' + this.id.match(/\d{0,}$/)[0]).toggle("slow");
 });
```

Comment: In your callback, `this` will refer to `#container`

Answer (score 1):

after you save the html into #container use this:

```
$('[id^="myBTN-"]', '#container').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('[id^="blah-"]').toggle('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.on()` method will bind to appended elements if used properly. http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
<div id="existingParent">
    <!--<div class="added-later">Hi!</div>-->
    <!--<div class="added-later">Hi!</div>-->
</div>
```

To listen for events on the added-later elements

```
$('#existingParent').on('click hover','.added-later', myFunction);
```

The method must be bound to an element that exists. $('body') can be used here, but at the cost of some performance I'd imagine.

Answer (score 0):

When you re trying to attach events added dynamically, a simple `.click()` won't do, you have to use `on`:

```
$("#newElementparent").on('click', "#newElement", function() {});
```

Comment: `$("#newElement").on('click', ` is identical to `$("#newElement").click(`

Comment: If you have to use `on` then you have to use the parent. Otherwise he can resort to the deprecated 'live' or `delegate`.

Comment: What I was suggesting is you might as well use `document` as the parent. Perhaps being specific is still more efficient.

Comment: Yeah, `document` should do. Basically it requires an ancestor, so I thought I would suggest parent.

Answer (score -1):

You'd do better to build the element on the fly:

```
 var container = $('<div>');
 for (var i = 0; i < op.length; i++) {
     container.append(
         $('<div>').append(
             $('<div>').text(op[i]['Field1']).click(function() {
                 $(this).next('div').toggle("slow"); 
             }),
             $('<div>').text(op[i]['Field2'])
         )
     );
 }
 $('#container').empty().append(container);
```

Comment: If possible you should always build a complete string and add that all in one. That is much faster than multiple appends!

Comment: @kannix: Not sure I believe that: The string will get parsed into the DOM anyway. Why not just build the DOM and skip out the string?

Comment: Have a look at this video: http://vimeo.com/18846584 why a complete string is faster.. btw i didn't downvote your post!

Comment: @kannix: NVM, found the bit you were refering to. Not sure it applied here - Remember, I'm only modifying the page DOM on the last line. Up untilt that point, I'm building my own DOM, essentially using `createElement` rather than passing a string.

Comment: Sry, have forgotten that the video was that long ;) It starts around 17:30